# Cycle through elements in list to assign different colors to plot

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I have a main list made of `N` sub-lists (where this number will change for different runs), each one containing pairs of `x,y` points. I need a way to plot the points in these sub-lists with different colors, taken from a list with (usually) fewer elements than sub-lists. To do this I need a way to *cycle* through this list of colors. This is an excerpt of what I'm after:

```
# Main list which holds all my N sub-lists.
list_a = [[x,y pairs], [..], [..], [..], ..., [..]]

# Plot sub-lists with colors taken from this list. I need the for block below
# to cycle through this list.
col = ['red', 'darkgreen', 'blue', 'maroon','red']

for i, sub_list in enumerate(list_a):
    plt.scatter(sub_list[0], sub_list[1], marker='o', c=col[i])
```

If `len(col) < len(list_a)` (which will happen most of the time) this will return an error. Since for a given run of my code the number of sub-lists will vary, I can't hard code a number of colors into the `col` list, so I need a way to *cycle* through that list of colors. How could I do that?

Comment: Look at `itertools.cycle()` - that's exactly what it's for :-)

Comment: @thefourtheye: that would be `col[0]` and `col[1]` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), and then instead of `c=col[i]`, use `next`.  For example:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> cols = cycle(["red", "green", "blue"])
>>> next(cols)
'red'
>>> next(cols)
'green'
>>> next(cols)
'blue'
>>> next(cols)
'red'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use modulo operator

```
numberOfColors = len(col)
for i, sub_list in enumerate(list_a):
    plt.scatter(sub_list[0], sub_list[1], marker='o', c=col[i % numberOfColors])
```

Comment: Upvote for not depending on extra packages. The one by DSM looks a bit simpler but his one is also very good. Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel `itertools` is part of the standard installation, so it isn't something exotic.  You can do pretty amazing things with `itertools`....